# MySQL WorkbenchからDBに接続できない

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbenchを最近使い始めた者です。
ずっと使えていたのですが、今日（2022/6/22）起動しようとすると以下のようなエラーが出ました。[image: WB起動時のエラー]

以下は試しました。

- 環境変数のPATHにC:¥Windows¥System32を追加
- コマンドプロンプトからchcpと打って932が返ることの確認
- コマンドプロンプトからmysqlに接続（サーバに接続できないとのメッセージが出ました）

色々調べましたが、よく分かりませんでした。
何か解消方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。
環境はWindows10 21H2（64bit）、MySQLWBはver.8.0.28です。

エラーログの一部も以下に載せておきます。

> 22:34:38 [INF][      Workbench]: UI is up
> 22:34:38 [INF][      Workbench]: Running the application
> 22:34:45 [ERR][SQL Editor Form]: SqlEditorForm: exception in do_connect method: Exception: Unable to connect to localhost
> 22:34:45 [WRN][SQL Editor Form]: Unable to connect to localhost
> 22:34:45 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
> 22:34:45 [INF][SQL Editor Form]: Error 2003 connecting to server, assuming server is down and opening editor with no connection
> 22:34:46 [INF][        WQE.net]: Launching SQL IDE
> 22:34:48 [INF][        WQE.net]: SQL IDE UI is ready
> 22:34:52 [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:init:307]: Error connecting to MySQL: Unable to connect to localhost (code 2003)
> 22:34:52 [ERR][wb_server_management.py:local_run_cmd_windows:407]: Exception executing local command: chcp.com: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 0: invalid start byte
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\wb_server_management.py", line 404, in local_run_cmd_windows
> retcode = OSUtils.exec_command(command, output_handler)
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\os_utils.py", line 360, in exec_command
> for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, ""):
> File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\Python\Lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
> (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8c in position 0: invalid start byte
>
> 22:34:52 [WRN][wb_server_management.py:fetch_windows_shell_info:654]:
> ProcessOpsWindowsLocal.fetch_windows_shell_info(): WARNING: Unable to
> determine codepage from shell: "" 22:34:58
> [ERR][wb_admin_control.py:server_polling_thread:561]: Error creating
> SQL connection for monitoring: MySQLError('Unable to connect to
> localhost (code 2003)') 22:34:58 [ERR][       pymforms]: Unhandled
> exception in Python code:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\wb_admin_grt.py",
> line 401, in 
> ignore = mforms.Utilities.add_timeout(0.1, lambda: context.open_into_section("admin_server_status", True))   File
> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\modules\wb_admin_grt.py",
> line 329, in open_into_section
> page = page_class(self.ctrl_be, self.server_profile, self.admin_tab)   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench
> 8.0\modules\wb_admin_server_status.py", line 234, in **init**
> self.status = wb_admin_monitor.WbAdminMonitor(server_profile, self.ctrl_be)   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench
> 8.0\modules\wb_admin_monitor.py", line 251, in **init**
> self.mon_be = wba_monitor_be.WBAdminMonitorBE(UPDATE_INTERVAL, server_profile, ctrl_be, self.widgets, self.cpu_widget, sql)   File
> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench
> 8.0\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 398, in **init**
> self.wmimon = WMIStats(ctrl_be, server_profile, cpu_widget)   File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench
> 8.0\modules\wba_monitor_be.py", line 343, in **init**
> raise Exception("Current profile has no WMI enabled") # TODO Should be better message Exception: Current profile has no WMI enabled

Comment: コマンドプロンプトで起動できていないのであればMySQLWorkBenchの問題ではなくてMySQL自体の問題のように見受けられます。MySQLは間違いなく起動していますか？いままでどのようにMySQLを起動していましたか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。サービスがなぜか停止していました。
お騒がせしました。。

Answer (score 1):

MySQLのサービスが停止していたことが原因でした。
サービスを開始したら接続できるようになりました。